pandas pivot multiple columns
I want this but got that
I want to transfer 2 columns at the same time, but they are directly flattened. How can I make multiple columns appear directly on the row?
import pandas as pd

ll = [
    ["ci", "2024-01", "100", "10"],
    ["test", "2024-01", "100", "10"],
    ["prd", "2024-01", "100", "10"],
    ["ci", "2024-02", "100", "10"],
    ["test", "2024-02", "100", "10"],
    ["prd", "2024-02", "100", "10"],
    ["ci", "2024-03", "100", "10"],
    ["test", "2024-03", "100", "10"],
    ["prd", "2024-03", "100", "10"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(ll)

df.columns = [
    "account",
    "month",
    "cost1",
    "cost2",
]
df1 = pd.pivot(
    df,
    index="account",
    columns="month",
    values=["cost1", "cost2"],
)
print(df1)

